# Difficulty reading this razor syntax nested if else

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having problem reading this razor syntax that comes from an existing template.

```
<div class="@(HasText(columnclass) ? columnclass == "myColumns-1" || columnclass == "myColumns-2" ? "col-md-12" : columnclass == "myColumns-12" ? "col-md-6" : "col-md-12" : "col-md-12")">
```

Is the above the same as:

```
 @if(HasText(columnclass))
{
    if(columnclass == "myColumns-1" || columnclass == "myColumns2")
    {
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    }

    else if (columnclass == "myColumns-12")
    {
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    }

}
else
{
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
}
```

Can the first complex razor syntax instead be used in a html.extension or even a func<>?

Comment: You got the `if` statements right but I don't really understand the part of your question relating to an Html extension and Func<>. That not a "_complex razor syntax"; that's just a plain old [ternary `if`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) expression that returns a `string` which Razor writes as the class of your `div`. It should work almost everywhere. You can even write `@Html.ActionLink(4==4?"Four":"Not four", "DummyAction")` and still work.

Comment: Ok, its not a complex razor syntax but I was just wondering how to read the nested if elses in the shorthand syntax.

Comment: You read it right. I find it easier to break such expressions in multiple lines and indent the "sub `if`s". I becomes apparent afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple Extension -

```
public static class DivExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Div(this HtmlHelper html, string input)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            return new MvcHtmlString("<div class=\"col-md-12\"></div>");

         if (input == "myColumns-12")
             return new MvcHtmlString("<div class=\"col-md-6\"></div>");

         return new MvcHtmlString("<div class=\"col-md-12\"></div>");
    }
}
```

usage -

```
@using MVC.NameSpaceOfExtension

@Html.Div("myColumns-6")
```

**NOTE:** I cannot guarantee the logic in my extension method. Please do test it on your side and if there is a problem in logic, then please replace it with your logic.